# How to create a counter using recursion to get the total employees(direct or indirect) under a manager_id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, counter, papaparse

I have an excel file with data like this

| Name | WorkerId | ManagerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 179 | 180 |
| Liz | 150 | 179 |
| Ricki | 120 | 179 |
| sona | 113 | 150 |
| Preet | 558 | 150 |
| mina | 89 | 558 |
| Yukti | 45 | 120 |

And I want a function CountEmployee(manager_id) that will return all the employees under him. For example:

CountEmployee(179) = 6 ,
CountEmployee(150) = 3

I am using papa parse library to parse this excel into object, and wrote an recursive function to get the total employee.

> **parseCsv** to parse the csv

```
 function parseCsv() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Papa.parse("Employees.csv", {
      download: true,
      complete: function (results) {
        return resolve(results);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

> **CountDirectEmployees** to get the Direct employees of a manager Id

```
 async function CountDirectEmployee(data) {
      var countDirect1 = 0
       const results = await parseCsv();
        results.data.map((row, index) => {
                        if (row[2] == data) {
                           countDirect1 = countDirect1 +  1
                        }
                    })
     return countDirect1;
    }
```

And finally,

> The **CountEmployee** should return the final count

```
 async function CountEmployee(data,count) {
         const results = await parseCsv();
         CountDirectEmployee(data).then(
         function(count1){

         results.data.forEach((row, index) => {
                         if (row.ManagerId == data) {
                     count1 = count+count1
               CountEmployee(row[1],count1)
              }
         })
        } 
        )
       return count
   }
```

I know my logic is wrong for CountEmployee function, somewhere. Not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `.map()` or your `.map()` callback doesn't return anything then `.map()` is the wrong tool

Comment: data.map I just used to loop over the results.data array, what do you suggest I should return from the map.

Comment: _"data.map I just used to loop over the results"_ - Then `,map()` is definitely the wrong tool...

Comment: Updated the code, instead of map using for loop now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code slightly will allow us to call CountEmployee recursively. We'd pass in the rows variable for each call (to save reading in repeatedly), then add each employee's direct worker count to get the total for each manager.

The `getDirectEmployees()` function uses a simple Array.filter() to return the employees working directly for each manager.

```js
const employees = [ 
    [ 'Tom', 179, 180 ],
    [ 'Liz', 150, 179 ],
    [ 'Ricki', 120, 179 ],
    [ 'Sona', 113, 150 ],
    [ 'Preet', 558, 150 ],
    [ 'Mina', 89, 558 ],
    [ 'Yukti', 45, 120 ]
];
    
// Simulate what papa parse returns...
function parseCSV() {
    return Promise.resolve(employees); 
}

function displayRow(...row) {
    console.log(...row.map(f => (f + '').padEnd(15)))
}

async function testCounts() {
    console.log('Direct and total counts for each worker:\n');

    let rows = await parseCSV();
    displayRow('Name', 'Id', 'Direct', 'Total')
    for(let [name, workerId, managerId] of rows) {
        let directEmployees = CountDirectEmployees(workerId, rows);
        let totalEmployees = CountEmployee(workerId, rows);
        displayRow(name, workerId, directEmployees, totalEmployees)
    }
}

function getDirectEmployees(id, rows) {
    return rows.filter(([name, workerId, managerId]) => managerId === id);
}

function CountDirectEmployees(managerId, rows) {
    return getDirectEmployees(managerId, rows).length;
}
 
function CountEmployee(managerId, rows) {
    // Count direct employees, then count employees of each of these
    let directEmployees = getDirectEmployees(managerId, rows);
    let count = directEmployees.length;
    for(let [name, workerId] of directEmployees) {
        count += CountEmployee(workerId, rows);
    }
    return count;
}
 
testCounts()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, good point @Andreas, no code path needs this... thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Terry, this solution works and the execution time is also improved with using filter.